# getting list of values with list of keys for dictionary in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary

Suppose I use containers map to create a dictionary in MATLAB which has the following map:

```
1-A;
2-B;
3-C;
```

Denote the dictionary as D.

Now I have an input list `[2,1,3]`, and what I am expecting is `[B,A,C]`. The problem is, I can't just use `[2,1,3]` as the input list for D, but only input `2,1 and 3` one by one for D and get `B, A, C` each time. 
This can get the job done but as you can see, it's a bit less efficient.

So my question is: is there anything else I can do to let the dictionary return the whole list at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can find there is no one-step solution like python's `dict.items`. You can, however, get in a few lines. `mydict.keys()` gives you the keys of the dict as a cell array, and `mydict.values()` gives you the values as a cell array, so you can (in theory) combine those:

```
>> mykeys = mydict.keys();
>> myvals = mydict.values();
>> mypairs = [mykeys',myvals']
mypairs =
  3×2 cell array
    'A'    [1]
    'B'    [2]
    'C'    [3]
```

However, in principle maps are unordered, and I can't find anything in the MATLAB documentation that says that the order returns by `keys` and the order returned by `values` is necessarily consistent ([unlike Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)). So if you want to be extra safe, you can call `values` with a cell array of the keys you want, which in this case would be all the keys:

```
>> mykeys = mydict.keys();
>> myvals = mydict.values(mykeys);
>> mypairs = [mykeys',myvals']
mypairs =
  3×2 cell array
    'A'    [1]
    'B'    [2]
    'C'    [3]
```